# Android and OpenGL: can't call glGetString(..)

Tags: android, opengl-es

Would you please explain what is the problem with this simple code for determining [OpenGL extensions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#gl-extension-query) :

`String extensions = javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);`

If I put this in the code, I'm getting the error:

> "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   glGetString(int) from the type GL10"

So it just doesn't compile.

I'm using `ADT 22.6.1` and also `SDK 22.6.1`. The project doesn't create any `OpenGL`-related classes, only gets the info.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this data from GL10 object, example:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html#onSurfaceCreated(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html#onSurfaceCreated%28javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10,%20javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig%29)

Comment: Thanks, it helps. So the straight-forward example in the official documentation doesn't work nowadays